# Merge records in SuiteScript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

How can I merge 2 records in SuiteScript 1.0?

For example; I want to merge 2 customer records. The reason being we have many customers in our NetSuite backend that have not registered in our website. When they register NetSuite automatically creates a new customer instead of consolidating the existing customer. So I want to merge/consolidate those 2 records.

I have found `nlapiMergeRecord(id, baseType, baseId, altType, altId, fields)` but the help documentation says this function is now deprecated...

> THIS API HAS BEEN DEPRECATED
>
> This API is deprecated as of NetSuite Version 2015 Release 1. This function will no longer be supported as of Version 2016 Release 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nlapiMergeRecord` actually does/did something completely different to what you are looking for. It was used for merging a record with a template to create a "mail merge".

For merging duplicate records in SuteScript 1.0 you can use the [Job Manager APIs](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3074192.html)

```
var manager = nlapiGetJobManager('DUPLICATERECORDS');
var mergeJobRequest = manager.createJobRequest();
mergeJobRequest.setEntityType(mergeJobRequest.ENTITY_LEAD);
mergeJobRequest.setMasterSelectionMode(mergeJobRequest.MASTERSELECTIONMODE_CREATED_
   EARLIEST);
mergeJobRequest.setRecords(duplicateRecords);
mergeJobRequest.setOperation(mergeJobRequest.OPERATION_MERGE);
jobId = manager.submit(mergeJobRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you do this in SuiteScript 1.0; you can still try the Deprecated API. Deprecated doesn't necessarily mean deactivated.

In SuiteScript 2.0, you can use the `N/task` module to kick off an `EntityDeduplicationTask`, which gives you similar functionality to the Deduplication actions in the UI.

You can merge, delete, make parent-child, or mark as not duplicates, and you can select which record becomes the master based on certain criteria.